# How do I order the bars in all bar groups on a grouped bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a grouped bar chart with ggplot2. I have this code...

```
ggplot(data = dummy,
       aes(
         fill = Geography2,
         x = Group,
         y = PunishmentRate
       )
) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.5
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(data = subset(dummy, Group == "White"),
            aes(
              label = Geography2,
              y = 0
            ),
            position = position_dodge(0.5),
            hjust = 0
  )
```

That makes this chart...

[image]

The `dummy` data frame looks like this, in comma-separated format...

```
Group,Enrollment,Punished,PunishmentRate,Geography2
Total,2001957,302878,0.1512909618,State
Black,436329,117791,0.2699591363,State
Hispanic,625588,72974,0.1166486569,State
White,855256,96396,0.1127101125,State
Total,151818,14159,0.0932629859,Local
Black,38933,6816,0.175069992,Local
Hispanic,53690,3789,0.0705718011,Local
White,53036,2925,0.055151218,Local
```

How do I edit my code so that the "Local" bars display before the "State" bars?

Comment: Changing the factor order changes the order of the bars.  If you're labeling the bars I'm guessing you no longer want a legend, but if you do and want the bar order and legend order to match you can see my post [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/01/19/reversing-the-order-of-a-ggplot2-legend/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
dummy$Geography2 <- factor(dummy$Geography2, levels = c('State', 'Local'))
```

and re-run the plot. The lowest ordered factor (currently, 'Local' because it comes before 'State' if ordering alphabetically) appears as the bottom bar.